# Is it possible to fetch data using where clause with child relationship laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

hope you all doing great.

I just moved to Laravel recently from CI.

I have two tables 
 - Bookings
 - Booked_Rooms

What i want is if all the rooms are checked_out which i will decide by using Booked_Rooms.checkout_at is null then parent record should exclude from data set.

I tried google and did little bit research but couldn't find what i am actually looking.

I also tried `Booking:with(array('rooms',function($q){ // where query }))` but it is still fetching the parent record. I don't want to traverse every single record by loop and then excluding the records because it doesn't looks good for performance measurement. I also know that i can do this by using join but can i do this using Eloquent ORM

Summary : If all the checkout_at columns of all booked_rooms are not null then the parent booking record is considered as completed and shouldn't be in pending bookings.

HtlBooking Model Class

```
public function rooms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\BookedRoom','booking_id');
}
```

Controller Function

```
$bookings = HtlBooking::with ( 'rooms' )->with ( 'user' )
        ->get ();
```

Answer (score 3):

Found my answer, just did it by using

```
$bookings = HtlBooking::with('rooms')->whereHas('rooms',function($q){$q->where('checkout_at',null);})->with ( 'user' )
        ->get ();
```